# Trying to add karma to acts_as_votable

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, acts-as-votable

Im trying to add karma to acts_as_votable. Lost! Please help.

Basically I have a up/down vote working on the Articles.

I would like to add 1 to publishers karma each time their article is upvoted. (and subtract 1 when one is downvoted). So in a nutshell when someone votes on an article the article gets a vote and the publisher gets a karma point.

I have the voting of articles working just fine.

I followed this tutorial 
(https://masteruby.github.io/weekly-rails/2014/08/12/how-to-add-user-karma-to-rails-app.html)
to try to implement adding karma to publishers when an article is voted on but I keep getting this error in the logs.

```
NoMethodError - undefined method `increase_karma' for #<Publisher:0x000001055d6f00>
```

I've run the migrations and restarted server multiple times.

In my Article Controller (Im also using friendly_id)

```
def upvote
  @article = Article.find_by_slug(params[:id])
  @article.upvote_by current_user
  @article.publisher.increase_karma
  respond_to do |format|
    format.html { redirect_to :back }
    format.js { render layout: false }
  end
end
```

In my Publishers Controller

```
  def increase_karma(count=1)
    update_attribute(:karma, karma + count)
  end

  def decrease_karma(count=1)
    update_attribute(:karma, karma - count)
  end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason why Rails is throwing an error is because your Publisher Model doesn't have a `increase_karma` method.

`increase_karma` and `decrease_karma` methods should be moved to the `Publisher` model from the `Publisher` Controller and it should eliminate the error.

```
  def increase_karma(count=1)
    update_attribute(:karma, karma + count)
  end

  def decrease_karma(count=1)
    update_attribute(:karma, karma - count)
  end
```

Comment: Hi - Thanks - I noticed that about an hour after I submitted the question. One of those nights with not enough coffee ;/